# Devise Omniauth-facebook bypass rails validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth

I just followed [this article](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview) to implement omniauth in my rails 4 app.

In my User model, I have two types of users, namely ADMIN(created by form) and MEMBER(created by omniauth). I need to bypass ALL the validations for MEMBER user who will be created by omniauth.

I know that this could be done by passing this option:

```
save(validate: false)
```

However, first_or_create method was adopted:

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    # where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
      user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
    end
  end
```

**So, my question is: How do I bypass ALL the validations in this omniauth case?**

Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`first_or_create` doesn't seem to take any options, but you still have a couple options.

Instead of `first_or_create`, you could do `first_or_initialize`, which works the same as `first_or_create` but doesn't save. You would then have a new record that you could call `save(validate: false)` on

But, then you'd have records in the system that aren't valid, so if you go to update one of these records' emails, for instance, you would have to get around the validations again.

What I would suggest is moving this logic to the validations themselves:

```
validate_presence_of :name, unless: -> { from_omniauth? }

private

def from_omniauth?
  provider && uid
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But I cannot do that in DRY principle,`unless from_omniauth?
    validates :name, length: { in: 1..77}
    validates :keywords, length: { in: 0..50}
  end` I need to do this: `validates :name, unless: -> { from_omniauth? }` one by one. So, I am curious how to clean up this by checking `unless` condition in one go.